# Symfony 20 Minute Page Load Times

Tags: symfony, page-load-time

Does anyone have a clue why in the world I would be getting 20 minute page load times in dev in Symfony2? It just randomly happens to me. One day I will get fast load times, the next day I am twiddling my thumbs waiting for a page to load. What can I check/disable/enable/etc? Thanks!

Here is my latest page load:

Time:  298068 ms

[image: Screen Shot of Issue]

**Here is the Entity for PurchaseOrder**

```
 /**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="archived_po_number", type="string", length=50, nullable=true)
 * @Common\Versioned
 */
private $archived_po_number;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=50, nullable=true)
 * @Common\Versioned
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="show_locations", type="string", length=1, nullable=true)
 * @Common\Versioned
 */
private $show_locations;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="freight", type="decimal", precision=10, scale=2, nullable=true)
 * @Common\Versioned
 */
private $freight;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="pallets", type="integer", nullable=true)
 * @Common\Versioned
 */
private $pallets;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="boxes", type="integer", nullable=true)
 * @Common\Versioned
 */
private $boxes;

/**
 * @var text
 * @ORM\Column(name="internal_notes", type="text", nullable=true)
 * @Common\Versioned
 */
private $internal_notes;

/**
 * @var text
 * @ORM\Column(name="sales_rep_notes", type="text", nullable=true)
 * @Common\Versioned
 */
private $sales_rep_notes;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="custom_purchase_order_number", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 * @Common\Versioned
 */
private $custom_purchase_order_number;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="WIC\CommonBundle\Entity\CustomOptions", inversedBy="purchaseOrders")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="purchase_order_class", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
 * @Common\Versioned
 */
private $purchase_order_class;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="WIC\WarehouseBundle\Entity\Warehouse", inversedBy="purchaseOrders")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="generated_by_location", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
 * @Common\Versioned
 */
private $generated_by_location;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="WIC\InventoryLocationBundle\Entity\InventoryLocation", inversedBy="purchaseOrders")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="receive_location", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
 * @Common\Versioned
 */
private $receive_location;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="WIC\WarehouseBundle\Entity\Warehouse", inversedBy="purchaseOrders")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="company_name", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
 * @Common\Versioned
 */
private $company_name;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="WIC\WarehouseBundle\Entity\Warehouse", inversedBy="purchaseOrders")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="ship_to", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
 * @Common\Versioned
 */
private $ship_to;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="WIC\WarehouseBundle\Entity\Warehouse", inversedBy="purchaseOrders")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="bill_to", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
 * @Common\Versioned
 */
private $bill_to;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="WIC\CommonBundle\Entity\CustomOptions", inversedBy="purchaseOrders")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="payment_terms", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
 * @Common\Versioned
 */
private $payment_terms;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="WIC\CommonBundle\Entity\CustomOptions", inversedBy="purchaseOrders")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="fob", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
 * @Common\Versioned
 */
private $fob;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="WIC\CommonBundle\Entity\CustomOptions", inversedBy="purchaseOrders")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="ship_via", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
 * @Common\Versioned
 */
private $ship_via;

/**
 * @var datetime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="ship_by", type="datetime", nullable=true)
 * @Common\Versioned
 */
private $ship_by;

/**
 * @var datetime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="cancel_by", type="datetime", nullable=true)
 * @Common\Versioned
 */
private $cancel_by;

/**
 * @var datetime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="due_by", type="datetime", nullable=true)
 * @Common\Versioned
 */
private $due_by;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="nbt", type="string", length=2, nullable=true)
 * @Common\Versioned
 */
private $nbt;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="WIC\PurchaseOrderLineItemBundle\Entity\PurchaseOrderLineItem", mappedBy="purchaseOrder", cascade={"remove"}, fetch="EAGER")
 */
protected $purchaseOrderLineItem;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="WIC\PurchaseOrderBundle\Entity\PurchaseOrderCharge", mappedBy="purchaseOrder", cascade={"remove"}, fetch="EAGER")
 */
protected $purchaseOrderCharge;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="WIC\PurchaseOrderBundle\Entity\PurchaseOrderPayment", mappedBy="purchaseOrder", cascade={"remove"}, fetch="EAGER")
 */
protected $purchaseOrderPayment;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="WIC\SupplierBundle\Entity\Supplier", inversedBy="purchaseOrders")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="supplier_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
 * @Common\Versioned
 */
protected $supplier;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="WIC\CommonBundle\Entity\CustomOptions", inversedBy="purchaseOrders")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="status_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
 * @Common\Versioned
 */
private $status;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="WIC\UserBundle\Entity\User")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="created_by", referencedColumnName="id")
 * @Common\Blameable(on="create")
 */
private $createdBy;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="WIC\UserBundle\Entity\User")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="updated_by", referencedColumnName="id")
 * @Common\Blameable(on="update")
 */
private $updatedBy;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="WIC\AccountBundle\Entity\Account", inversedBy="purchaseOrders")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="account_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
 * @Common\Versioned
 * @Common\Blameable(on="create")
 */
protected $account;

/**
 * @var datetime $created
 *
 * @Common\Timestampable(on="create")
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
 */
private $created;

/**
 * @var datetime $updated
 *
 * @Common\Timestampable(on="update")
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
 */
private $updated;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="deletedAt", type="datetime", nullable=true)
 */
private $deletedAt;
```

**Here is my controller method listAction()**

```
    // verify access
    if (false === $this->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')) {
        $classIdentity = new ObjectIdentity('class', 'WIC\\PurchaseOrderBundle\\Entity\\PurchaseOrder');
        if (false === $this->get('security.context')->isGranted('VIEW', $classIdentity)) {
            throw new AccessDeniedException('Only an admin user has access to this section...');
        }
    }

    // get user's account
    $account = $this->getUser()->getAccount();

    $search_form = $this->createForm(new PurchaseOrderSearchType());

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
        $search_form->bind($request);
        // if ($search_form->isValid()) {
        $data = $search_form->getData();
        $purchaseOrders = $em->getRepository('WICPurchaseOrderBundle:PurchaseOrder')->getListBy($data);
        // }
    } else {

        if($this->get('request')->query->get('letter')){

        }else{

        }

        // Set the up the pagination statement...
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $dql   = "SELECT p FROM WIC\PurchaseOrderBundle\Entity\PurchaseOrder p WHERE p.account=:account_id ORDER BY p.created desc";
        $query = $em->createQuery($dql);
        $query->setParameters(array(
            'account_id' => $account->getId(),
        ));

        $paginator  = $this->get('knp_paginator');
        $paginatorObject = $paginator->paginate(
            $query,
            $this->get('request')->query->get('page', 1),25
        );

        // $purchaseOrders = $em->getRepository('WICPurchaseOrderBundle:PurchaseOrder')->findByAccount($account->getId(),array('id' => 'DESC'));
    }

    return array(
        'heading' => 'Purchase Order',
        'sidebarLeftTitle'=>'Purchase Order Menu',
        'purchaseOrders' => $paginatorObject,
        'search_form' => $search_form->createView(),
    );
```

Comment: Do you need profiler? If you don't use it you can disable it in dev_config.yml and config.yml; this may help your speed.

Comment: Running under windows?  Check any network drives you might have.  I had an issue once with a misspelled drive name that seemed to randomly lock up the system.

Comment: looks like the security\http\firewall is creating the long page load times. why would this be happening?

Answer (score 1):

By default in `app_dev.php` you have the profiler bar, click on the timer and you will have a good start to debug (timeline with main/sub request, etc)

Comment: looks like the security\http\firewall is creating the long page load times. why would this be happening?

Answer (score 1):

The issue was in the OneToMany relationship code where it says fetch="EAGER". This was pulling in all sorts of unnecessary associations and db queries. When I removed it, the db queries went down to 4 per page instead of 4000.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using x-debug or any PHP level profiling? You've either got some form of recursion happening or one of the steps in the `security\http\firewall` process is taking a very long time to complete.

My suggestion would be

- Look at your stack-trace and find anywhere there are highly repeated events around the `security\http\firewall` code and investigate if they exist
- Quickly step through your code using x-debug, and find where the delay is occurring. With a few page reloads you should be able to *step into* the section which is causing the long page load times.
- If you are using profiling, make sure your created files aren't ridiculously verbose. I've seen this long page load issue happen before *due* to profiling, where each page load would create a 20Gb+ profiling file.

Comment: Its only happening on my Mac, my other developer is not getting the issue, his pages load in like 5 seconds in dev. He is on a windows machine.

Comment: Added a screenshot of my timeline.

Comment: Thats a **massive** number of database queries during your controller method, not during `security\http\firewall`. Can you post your controller method and the entity which relates to it?

Comment: Just added the Entity and the Controller Method.

Comment: Looking quickly at your controller, sometimes the behaviour you're describing can be caused by a search form using an 'entity' type, and there being a decent number of large entities that can be selected. i.e. 500 warehouses. All of these entities which make up the selection have to be hydrated and this can take considerable time. i.e. If you have 500 `Warehouse` entities which can be selected in your search form, doctrine will need to hydrate all 500 of these entities to create the search form.

Comment: In light of this, next time this 20 minute load time occurs, try reducing your `PurchaseOrderSearchType` to nothing but perhaps a name search (something that is just a 'scalar' styled input) and see if this solves the issue.

Comment: I totally removed it from the controller all together and its still the same issue.

Comment: I think it has to do with the remote db connection. When I move the db connection on to my local machine it works great. Any thoughts as to why the remote connection would be so sluggish?

Comment: By removing it from your controller did that bring the DB calls down? You are hitting the DB over 1k times, which obviously over a remote connection is going to take a bit longer. You need to figure out what is causing so many calls. If you click on the Doctrine tab in your profiler and scan through, what are the main calls being repeated?